# Which is an easy second order time integration method?

Tags: numerical-methods, heat-equation, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to numerically solve the simple 2d heat equation (without any source and all the thermal properties assumed to be constant) using FVM. I am looking for a second-order accurate implicit time integration method. I have searched on the subject and most lectures talk about the first-order implicit Euler method or second-order explicit Runge Kutta method. I have tried understanding the second-order implicit Runge Kutta method but have found it very difficult to understand.

i) Is there a better second-order implicit method for my purpose?
ii) Can someone please explain the implicit RK2 method?

Comment: What is the implicit RK2 method? The trapezoidal method? Why not use the 2-stage 4th order Gauß method as implicit method? Do you understand that Crank-Nicholson is the standard 2nd order implicit method for the heat equation and related parabolic PDE, which coincidentally is the implicit trapezoidal method in time direction?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ya I was thinking about implicit midpoint RK2 method (I think this is unconditionally stable? I am not sure). Now I think I will use the implicit trapezoidal method (but I think this is not unconditionally stable? please let me know if I am wrong). Also, I was under the impression Crank-Nicholson was a semi-implicit method? am I wrong in this understaind?

Comment: Both second order RK methods have the same stability function, in some experiences the midpoint method is less stable. As far as I know, CR is discretization by order 2 difference formulas in the space direction, dominantly the central second order difference, and the trapezoidal rule in time direction. Sometimes CR is presented more as a set of building blocks, then also other time discretizations may fall under this method. "Semi-implicit" requires qualification, as the most common use is for the symplectic Euler method which is only tangentially related to this situation.

Comment: You need to edit your question and include the definition of what you call the implicit second order RK method. It is highly unlikely that we can help you until then.